# Magento 2 Create multiple store views in an easy way?

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

I need to create more than 100 store views to my Magento website. Is there an "easy" way of doing this, like by using command line? It will take a long time if I create each store in admin -> stores -> all stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this via CLI as of yet (correct me if i'm wrong), but if you have the programming knowledge you can create console commands inside a module. With some searching I came across this;

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-How-to-create-website-Store-Store-view-Root-Category/m-p/88315#M3799

Even though, this will take some time to implement. Adding them manually will be eventually faster.